# Generate all locales in a docker image

Tags: ubuntu, docker, debian, locale, dockerfile

How can one generate all locales in a debian/ubuntu based docker image?

`locale-gen` doesn't accept the `-A`/`--all` option as described here: http://www.linuxhowtos.org/manpages/8/locale-gen.htm.

`dpkg-reconfigure locales` has an option to generate all locales in the interactive mode, but this is not available in a Dockerfile.

Just generating English or a fixed set of languages isn't enough and doesn't sound correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `/etc/locale.gen` I've found the hint, that `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED` lists all supported locale codes. As of https://people.debian.org/~schultmc/locales.html and https://wiki.debian.org/Locale it should be enough to add all wanted codes to `/etc/locale.gen` and run `locale-gen`. So this is my solution:

```
RUN cp /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED /etc/locale.gen
RUN locale-gen
```

Answer (score 0):

Just install precompiled locale data via package `locales-all` within your docker container. This also decreases build time because no locales have to be generated, see code in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/locales.postinst`.

Tricks like `RUN echo 'locales locales/locales_to_be_generated multiselect     All locales' | debconf-set-selections && dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales` didn't work for me, too.